# How to count lines in compressed file in a directory and print the number of lines per file?

Tags: linux

I am counting lines in several files in a directory without decompressing, and dividing the result by 4 as below:

```
gunzip -c *.fastq.gz | echo $((`wc -l`/4))
```

Everything looks good, except that it's giving me the total number of all the lines. I would like to print the lines per file. Can anyone help. I am using Darwin (Mac OSX). Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make it a small script?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.fastq.gz
do
   echo "$i" $(gunzip -c $i | echo `wc -l`/4 | bc -l)
done
```

If you want a one-liner:

```
for i in *.fastq.gz; do echo "$i" $(gunzip -c $i | echo `wc -l`/4 | bc -l); done
```

Comment: `for i in *.fastq.gz`... Not `for i in \`ls *.fastq.gz\``... Don't parse the output of `ls`...

Comment: @twalberg: very true, I corrected it (and the part I missed about dividing by 4).

Comment: thanks for the suggestions and corrections. working as expected.

Comment: @maeye, great. If this answers your question, you can mark it as such (by toggling the mark). People will start frowning if you don't mark accepted answers to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

`gzip` usually comes with `zcat` (maybe `gzcat`), which is essentially `gzip -dc`. So this invocation should work for a single file:

```
echo $(( $(zcat file.gz | wc -l) / 4 ))
```

If for some reason you don't have `zcat`, `gzip -dc` works just fine in its place.

Wrapping that in a `for` loop to handle different files should be relatively straightforward...